# How can I exclude Meteor platform code when searching a Meteor project in Atom?

Tags: windows, meteor, atom-editor

In Atom, I can either search for a string in the open file (which they call a "buffer") via Ctrl+F, or the entire project with Ctrl+Shift+F, but that also includes all the Meteor code (not written by me).

Normally when I'm searching the codebase, I'm just looking for stuff I wrote. How can I expand the search to include all of the files I've added to the project, but none of the Meteor platform files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some disagreement on the interwebs about whether or not this feature actually exists in Atom. [This post](https://discuss.atom.io/t/exclude-directory-from-open-file-search/6109) implies directories can be excluded from the fuzzy-finder. Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> to open the settings view and then enter the directory you wish to exclude (`.meteor`) in the dialog.

Comment: I don't have a Cmd key; is there a Windows equivalent?

Comment: From the [docs](https://github.com/atom/settings-view) You can open the Settings View by navigating to Edit > Preferences (Linux), Atom > Preferences (OS X), or File > Preferences (Windows).

Comment: It's actually File > Settings in Windows (maybe the docs are outdated?). And selecting it does nothing (there's no dialog); also, selecting Ctrl+, does nothing. Although I'm allergic to paying money for things, I am seriously considering WebStorm.

Comment: What was the final solution?

Comment: Ctrl + , to open the Settings dialog, then, as you said, entering ".meteor" into the "Ignored Names" edit. Ctrl+Shift+F and a string now only finds that string in my code - voila!